# HTML/CSS table different vertical margin for each index level

Tags: html, css, margin, space

I used a Python library to generate the HTML code for the following table"
[image]
As you can see, the table has multiple levels of index: `id`, `machine`, `component`, `time` (sorry, I don't have the header in the code right now!) and finally a column with a value (`RED`, `616`, etc).

What CSS property can I use to increase the space between rows? Specifically, I would like to be able to have a different spacing for different levels of index

- Really big space between two different `id` values
- Big space between two `machine` value with the same id
- Normal (not so big as above) space between `component` values of the same machine
- Small space between `time` values referring to the same components

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/120698745?noredirect=1) I was suggested to set

```
table {
  border-collapse:separate; 
  border-spacing: 0 1em;
}
```

However, this increases the overall space.

Note: I can edit CSS, not HTML (HTML is generated by a Python code).

HTML Code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122 th.col_heading.level0 {
        font-size: 1.5em;;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122 td {
        border: solid 1px #000;;
        padding: 10px;;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122 th {
        border: solid 1px #000;;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122 tr {
        margin: 0px 10px;;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122 thead {
        display: none;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row0_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row1_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row2_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row3_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row19_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row22_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row23_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row24_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row25_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row26_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row27_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row28_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row29_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row41_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row42_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row43_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row44_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row45_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row46_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row47_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row48_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row49_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row50_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row51_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row52_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row53_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row54_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row55_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row56_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row57_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row58_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row59_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row60_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row61_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row62_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row63_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row64_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row65_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row66_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row67_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row68_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row69_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row70_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row71_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row72_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row73_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row74_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row75_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row76_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row77_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row78_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row79_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row80_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row81_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row82_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row83_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row84_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row85_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row86_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row87_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row88_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row89_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row90_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row91_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row92_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row93_col0 {
        background-color: LightGray;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row4_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row11_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row18_col0 {
        background-color: LightGreen;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row5_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row6_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row7_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row8_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row9_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row10_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row12_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row13_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row14_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row15_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row16_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row17_col0 {
        background-color: white;
    }

    #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row20_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row21_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row30_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row31_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row32_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row33_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row34_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row35_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row36_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row37_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row38_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row39_col0, #T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row40_col0 {
        background-color: DarkRed;
    }</style>
<table id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="blank"></th>
        <th class="blank"></th>
        <th class="blank"></th>
        <th class="blank level0"></th>
        <th class="col_heading level0 col0">count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="index_name level0">id</th>
        <th class="index_name level1">machine type</th>
        <th class="index_name level2">component type</th>
        <th class="index_name level3">color</th>
        <th class="blank"></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <tr>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level0_row20" class="row_heading level0 row20" rowspan=2>
            id1
        </th>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level1_row20" class="row_heading level1 row20" rowspan=2>
            machine_1
        </th>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level2_row20" class="row_heading level2 row20">
            component A
        </th>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level3_row20" class="row_heading level3 row20">-</th>
        <td id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row20_col0" class="data row20 col0">RED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level2_row21" class="row_heading level2 row21">
            component B
        </th>
        <th id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122level3_row21" class="row_heading level3 row21">-</th>
        <td id="T_2e3dd8b4_dff8_11eb_a71b_acde48001122row21_col0" class="data row21 col0">RED</td>
    </tr>

                <tr>
                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level0_row4" class="row_heading level0 row4" rowspan=15>id 2</th>
                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level1_row4" class="row_heading level1 row4" rowspan=15>machine B</th>
                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level2_row4" class="row_heading level2 row4" >component A</th>
                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row4" class="row_heading level3 row4" >-</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row4_col0" class="data row4 col0" >GREEN</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level2_row5" class="row_heading level2 row5" rowspan=7>componenent C</th>
                        <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row5" class="row_heading level3 row5" >2021-07-06 15:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row5_col0" class="data row5 col0" >616</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row6" class="row_heading level3 row6" >2021-07-06 16:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row6_col0" class="data row6 col0" >494</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row7" class="row_heading level3 row7" >2021-07-06 17:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row7_col0" class="data row7 col0" >615</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row8" class="row_heading level3 row8" >2021-07-06 18:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row8_col0" class="data row8 col0" >729</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row9" class="row_heading level3 row9" >2021-07-06 19:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row9_col0" class="data row9 col0" >465</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row10" class="row_heading level3 row10" >2021-07-06 20:00:00-04:00</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row10_col0" class="data row10 col0" >0</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                                                <th id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122level3_row11" class="row_heading level3 row11" >-</th>
                        <td id="T_3a052c94_dffb_11eb_8e39_acde48001122row11_col0" class="data row11 col0" >OK</td>
            </tr>


    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works but it increase the space

Answer (score 0):

If the class names do not change, then the desired look can be achieved using `border-width` with transparency and selectors for adjacent elements.

```css
body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
}

thead { display: none; }

.row_heading,
.data {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0.5em;
  border: solid 0px #0000; /* border-color = transparent */
  box-shadow: inset -3px -2px 0 -1px #ccc, inset -1px 2px 0 -1px #ccc;
}
.level0,
.level0 + .level1,
.level0 + .level1 + .level2,
.level0 + .level1 + .level2 + .level3,
.level0 + .level1 + .level2 + .level3 + .data {
  border-top-width: 2em; /* Gap for ID */
}
.level1,
.level1 + .level2,
.level1 + .level2 + .level3,
.level1 + .level2 + .level3 + .data {
  border-top-width: 1em; /* Gap for Machine */
}
.level2,
.level2 + .level3,
.level2 + .level3 + .data {
  border-top-width: 0.5em; /* Gap for Component */
}

tr:first-child th,
tr:first-child td {
  border-top-width: 0px !important; /* No gap for first (top) section */
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="blank"></th>
      <th class="blank"></th>
      <th class="blank"></th>
      <th class="blank level0"></th>
      <th class="col_heading level0">count</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="index_name level0">id</th>
      <th class="index_name level1">machine type</th>
      <th class="index_name level2">component type</th>
      <th class="index_name level3">color</th>
      <th class="blank"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level0" rowspan=7>id1</th>
      <th class="row_heading level1" rowspan=2>machine_1</th>
      <th class="row_heading level2">component A</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">RED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level2">component B</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">RED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level1" rowspan=5>machine_2</th>
      <th class="row_heading level2">component A</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">RED</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level2" rowspan=3>component B</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">RED</td>
    </tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 16:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">494</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 17:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">615</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level2">component D</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">RED</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level0" rowspan=15>id 2</th>
      <th class="row_heading level1" rowspan=15>machine B</th>
      <th class="row_heading level2">component A</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">GREEN</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level2" rowspan=7>componenent C</th>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 15:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">616</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 16:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">494</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 17:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">615</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 18:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">729</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 19:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">465</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">2021-07-06 20:00:00-04:00</th>
      <td class="data">0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th class="row_heading level3">-</th>
      <td class="data">OK</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

> Some classes have been removed from HTML for code readability only. You only need to add the CSS without changing anything in your HTML!